# JavaScript Live search through containers

Tags: javascript

I am working on some line in JS to do a live search. I have been trying to modify this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

to do what I am looking for, how ever I cant seem to understand what I am doing wrong. any pointers or corrections are greatly appreciated.

> JS it should hide any twit that does not contain the search

```
    var navbarSearchbutton = document.getElementById('navbar-search-button')[0];
navbarSearchbutton.addEventListener('onkeyup', function() {
  searchFunction();
});

function searchFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, foo;
    foo = document.getElementsByClassName("twit");
    input = document.getElementById("navbar-search-input");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    li = document.getElementsByClassName("twit-text");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("P")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            foo[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

> HTML for the search box and what I am searching.

```
          <li class="navitem navbar-search">
        <input type="text" id="navbar-search-input" placeholder="Search...">
        <button type="button" id="navbar-search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

    <main class="twit-container">
  <article class="twit">
<div class="twit-icon">
  <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
</div>
<div class="twit-content">
  <p class="twit-text">
    A body in motion must remain in motion unless acted upon by an outside force.
  </p>
  <p class="twit-attribution">
    <a href="#">NewtonRulez</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are getting ('navbar-search-button by id. So, it will not return an id.
Second, the logic of searching by class name will not work. Below is an updated search function. I kept the same logic you are following to search for items by class names. You will need to to set the class name as twit-attribution for any new entry.

```
function searchFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, foo;
    foo = document.getElementsByClassName("twit");
    input = document.getElementById("navbar-search-input");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    li = document.getElementsByClassName("twit-attribution");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a.style.display = "";
        } else {
            a.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```